# Search field not clear for another list popup

Tags: javascript, angular, devextreme

I am using Devextreme module for a dxlist popup. I am able to open the popup and to show the list of items with a search input field but I have one more list popup. When I search in the first popup and close it, open the second popup, the search field text is not cleared.

```
    <dx-popup class="popup popupMore" [width]="500" [height]="500" [showTitle]="true" title="{{popupdata.name}}" [dragEnabled]="false"
  [closeOnOutsideClick]="true" [(visible)]="isVisible">

  <div class="list-container">
    <dx-list #list [dataSource]="popupdata.data" [height]="400" [searchEnabled]="true" 
      searchMode="contains"  >
      <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'item'">
        <div>{{data}}</div>
      </div>
    </dx-list>
  </div>
</dx-popup>
```

The above code is used in the html. Same popup will open for another two event.

Example: 
I have three buttons. When we click on each button we need to open the same popup with different data. When we click on the first button, this list popup will open with a search option. I searched in the search field and closed the popup. Then clicked the second button, same popup will open with new data but the search input field is not cleared.

Could anyone please help me, how to clear the search field for the next list popup that opens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dx-list` does **not** open a popup by default, it's just a list. Did you wrap it in a `dx-popup`?

Comment: can you share the code in stackblitz

Comment: Please share the code so everyone can help you with your problem

Comment: @briosheje Yes, wrap with dx-popup.

Comment: You can add an event listener to the `onShown` event raised by the `dxPopup`. `(onShown)="onPopupShown($event)"`. On that callback, you can get the `list` instance and alter the `searchValue` option by either binding it to the dx-list (`[(searchValue)]="_searchValue"` and by setting `this._searchValue = ''` in the onPopupShown event, or you may just want to simply alter the option through the `list` instance: `this.list.instance.option('searchValue','');`. Both will work.

Comment: Thanks Briosheje. Its working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, the cleverest approach I could think of is registering the `dxPopup`'s `onShown` event and, when fired, you may either:

- Reset the `list.instance` searchValue option (using `this.list.instance.option('searchValue','');`).
- Assign a two-way binded value to the `dx-list` component and reset that value. For that case, specifically, add `[(searchValue)]="_searchValue"` to the html dx-list tag, and add `this._searchValue = ''` in the `dxPopup`'s `onShown` callback.